# Javascript Value of Variable not updating in Servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I have simplified my Code to breakdown the Problem and to have a simple Example with a Timestamp for whats actually going wrong.
So please not be suprised why i do a AJAX call, this is for the real functionality of the Servlet.

Its a Servlet and the follwing code is part of a JSP page, im Working on JAVA 1.7 and a Tomcat 7. I run it in Firefox and Chrome.

My goal is to retrieve a value from a Java method and write it on the servlet page into the DIV *"ContentCharts"*. 
The Problem is that Javascript does not update the vaule of *"zeit"* and always writes the same Timestamp into the DIV-Container and on the Console

```
        $(document).ready(function()
        {       
            function ausgabe()
            {
                    <%
                    GregorianCalendar now = new GregorianCalendar();
                    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.LONG); 
                    String JZeit = df.format(now.getTime());
                    System.out.println("FKT ausgabe zeit:"+ JZeit);
                    %>  

                    var zeit='<%=JZeit %>';
                    console.info('Zeit:', zeit);
                    document.getElementById('ContentCharts').innerHTML  = zeit;
            }

            $("#subtab2").click(function()
             {

                $.ajax
                (
                    {
                        url:'overview',
                        data:{dbname:this.className},
                        type:'get',
                        cache:false,
                        success:function(){ausgabe();},
                        error:function(){alert('error');}       
                    }
                );
             }
         }
```

To test this I write the value of the JAVA varible *"Jzeit"* into the Serverlogs and get this [(Click to see the Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PF7w.png) results when I click the buttons three times. As you can see in the Picture here I get the right Timestamps.

Now I have also post the Value of the JS varialbe *"zeit"* into the Firebug Console. And now i get the Wrong time Stamps [(Click to see the Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0P7t.png)

The Content in the DIV is refreshing but here is the same Problem like in the Console, its always the same Timestamp.

These are my thoughts and Questions:

Why has the JS variable the wrong value when its right in JAVA?
Is there any option to say JS that it has to update the variable?
Could it be that JS saves the answers of the JAVA code and does not run it anymore, but runs the upper JAVA Code Snippet because there is no direct connection betwen JS and JAVA, like a value allocation?
How can i fix my Problem?

If you need more Informations to help me please ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

You're a bit confused about the ajax pattern.

Note that anything you write in `<%= jsp tags %>` will be rendered on the server, then sent to the client where it will never change. Therefore your `ausgabe` function will always return the same result when it is called. Subsequent calls to the function will not make repeated server requests, which is the behavior you're observing.

To fix this, the `success` function in your ajax call should take an argument which will be instantiated with the response from the server. The java code you've written in the jsp tags in the `ausgabe` function should be moved to the server and any variables you need should be returned from the `overview` endpoint. Then, the `ausgabe` function should be refactored to take an argument containing the server-calculated values, and update your page as desired.

Here is some reading on ajax requests:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/